# Identify mystery output on ssh login

Tags: ssh, x11, dbus, motd

How can I find where this dbus-launch error output is coming from? At first I thought it was related to motd but I currently have that disabled. X11Forwarding is turned off in my sshd_config as well as PrintMotd. It seems that something is trying to spawn an X session at login but I cannot find it. The server os is ubuntu 12.04. The pid doesnt exist when you go to look for it.

```
Using username "xxxx".
Last login: Tue Mar 11 13:58:10 2014 from my.host.name

** (process:5123): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=ef13d79dc4b8e04d585a623500000003 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n

** (process:5123): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=ef13d79dc4b8e04d585a623500000003 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
xxxx@qa:~$
```

Comment: Solved: After much hunting through ~/.profile, ~/.xsession and more, I finally found an entry that was added under /etc/profile.d/script.sh. Inside script.sh was a call to gsettings like so

    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///usr/share/backgrounds/picture-1920x1080.png

Because this was put below /etc/profile.d it was even launching on an ssh login, since this login had no gnome-session to set a background, it would fail. So my 'mystery' output was actually occuring **after** my ssh login had already completed
Simply commenting out the line solved my issue.